# Why does Jetty establish many connections when it starts up?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I've created a simple embedded jetty project based on the [OneConnector](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/OneConnector.html) example.

When I start the example I see one TCP connection in the listening state which I expected to see. There are also quite a few TCP connections in the established state.

Why are they there, how come there are so many and what are they used for?

In TCPView I see the following connections:

```
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:8080       my-pc.tfs.attix5.com:0   LISTENING      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56791      localhost:56792          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56792      localhost:56791          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56793      localhost:56794          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56794      localhost:56793          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56795      localhost:56796          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56796      localhost:56795          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56797      localhost:56798          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56798      localhost:56797          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56799      localhost:56800          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56800      localhost:56799          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56801      localhost:56802          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56802      localhost:56801          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56803      localhost:56804          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56804      localhost:56803          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56805      localhost:56806          ESTABLISHED      
java.exe:14536      TCP      my-pc:56806      localhost:56805          ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Yes I do. You're thinking one connection pair per thread?

Comment: it's possible that 8 Selectors are created; for each selector, a socket is established for the purpose of wakeup()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source code](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html), by default it goes like this...

```
_manager = new ServerConnectorManager(
                       getExecutor(),
                       getScheduler(),
                       selectors>0?
                       selectors:
                       Math.max(1,Math.min(4,Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()/2)
                       ));
addBean(_manager, true);
```

So that proves, it is based on the number of processors that you have is related to the number of selectors started by default.